# Best practice for Gradle api vs implementation in multi-module project

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, multi-module

This is not the commonly asked question about the difference between `api` and `implementation`, and hopefully will be more advance and interesting from the point of view of architecting a multi-module project.

Let say I have the following modules in an application

- `library`
- `base`
- `feature1`
- `feature2`
- `app`

Now the relations between the modules are:

`base` wraps `library`

`feature1` and `feature2` make use (depends) on `base`

`app` puts together `feature1` and `feature2`

Everything in this multi module structure should be able to work using Gradle's `implementation` dependencies and there's no need to use the `api` clause anywhere.

Now, let say `feature1` needs to access an implementation detail of `base` included in `library`.

In order to make `library` available to `feature1` we have two options as far as I can tell:

1. Change `implementation` for `api` in `base` to leak the dependency to modules that depend on `base`
2. Add `library` as an `implementation` dependency to `feature1` without having `base` leak the dependency on `library`

Of course the example has been simplified for the sake of the question, but you understand how this can became a configuration hell with a big number of modules with 4 or 5 levels of dependencies.

We could create a `base-feature` intermediate module that can wrap `base` and provide another level of abstraction for `feature1` to consume without leaking `library`, but let's leave that solution out of the scope of this problem to focus on the setup of the dependencies.

---

**Some trade-offs** that I detected on the above options:

Option 1) pros

- Smaller `build.gradle`'s files, as no need to repeat `implementation` clauses
- Faster build scrips edits. Just make the single change on the `api` clause and see the changes propagated to all consumer modules

Option 1) cons

- Classes might come up available in modules that shouldn't have access to them.
- Prone to miss use by developers, as they have implementations available and not only the module interfaces.

Option 2) pros

- It makes crystal clear which dependencies the module has.
- No guessing where the classes are coming from (think 4 or 5 levels of modules leaking dependencies), as their origin is always declared in the module dependencies.

Option 2) cons

- Makes updating a dependency more tedious, as all the modules with the `implementation` clause have to be modified. Even though I believe this is a good thing because it keeps track exactly of how a change modified the project, I see how it can take more time.

---

**Now the questions**:

- Is there any trade-offs in terms of compilation of this multi-module scenario?
- Is a module leaking a dependency "faster" to be compiled for consumer modules?
- Does it make a substantial difference in build times?
- What other side effects, pros/cons am I missing ?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Reposting from the [Gradle forum](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/best-practice-for-api-vs-implementation-in-multi-module-project/30519/2?u=ddimitrov) thread.

What you describe is a fairly common discussion about layered architecture systems, also known as "strict" vs "loose" layering, or "open" vs "closed" layers. See this (hopefully free for you too) chapter from [Software Architecture Patterns](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/software-architecture-patterns/9781491971437/ch01.html) for some semiotics which is unlikely to help you much with your choice

From my point of view, if a module needs to break layering, I'd model the project structure to expose this in the most direct and visible way. In this case it means adding `library` as implementation dependency of `feature1`.  Yes it makes the diagram uglier, yes it forces you to touch few more files on upgrade, and that is the point - your design has a flaw and it is now visible.

If few modules need to break the layer encapsulation in the same way, I may consider adding a separate base module exposing that functionality, with a name such as `base-xyz`. Adding a new module is a big thing, not because of the technical work, but because  our brain can handle only so many "things" at a time (chunking). I believe the same would hold for Gradle "variants" when they become available, but I can't claim that yet as I haven't tried them hands on.

If all clients of the `base` module need to access `library` (i.e. because you use classes or exceptions from `library` in your public signatures) then you should expose `library` as API dependency of `base`. The downside of that is that `library` becomes part of the public API of `base`, and it is probably bigger than you would like, and not under your control. Public API is something you are responsible for, and you want to keep it small, documented, and backwards compatible.

At this point you may be thinking about jigsaw modules (good), osgi (err... don't), or wrapping the parts of lib that you need to expose in your own classes (maybe?)

Wrapping only for the sake of breaking dependencies is not always a great idea. For one it increases the amount of code you maintain and (hopefully) document. If you start doing small adaptations in the `base` layer, and the `library` is a  well known library, you introduce (value added) inconsistencies - one needs to always be on guard whether their assumptions for lib still hold. Finally, often the thin wrappers end up leaking the library design, so even if they wrap the API - that still forces you to touch the client code when you replace/upgrade lib, at which point you may have been better off using lib directly.

So, as you can see, is about trade-offs and usability. The CPU doesn't care where your module boundaries lie, and all developers are different - some cope better with large amount of simple things, some cope better with small number of highly abstract concepts.

Don't obsess about the best (as in What Would Uncle Bob Do) design when any good design would work. The amount of extra complexity that is justified for the sake of introducing order is a fuzzy quantity, and is something that you are in charge of deciding. Make you best call and don't be afraid to change it tomorrow :-)

Comment: What kind of leak are we talking about?
If I use ```implementation``` in libraries, then in the host application I will be forced to write something like

     ```implementation library
     implementation wraps
     implementation base```

Otherwise app will be a crash in runtime.
Those, there will be a ```wraps``` and ```base``` leak anyway.

If I use ```api``` in libraries, then in the host application I will be forced to write something like
     ```implementation library```

and it's all. and here will also be your "leak"

Comment: Apologies, but I don't understand your question. What part of my answer are you referring? What do you mean by the code-formatted: base, wraps, library, implementation? A bit of quoting and context would help, though I appreciate it is difficult to do in SO comment. Care to move the discussion to the linked thread on the Gradle forum?

Comment: Just passing through few years later - Gradle's "platforms" are a good way to bundle the version of libs that are always used together. One day I may update the answer above, but meanwhile make sure to read the docs :-)